# How to embed a mp3 to start at a specific timestamp?

Tags: html, mp3, timestamp

The question says it all. I want to play a mp3 on a webpage and be able to set the timestamp at which the mp3 starts and stops playing.

Comment: Warning: This is likely to be really annoying to your users.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The idea is to play the mp3 after the user clicks on "play" but start playing from the fifth second.

Comment: I did misunderstand the question. Is this some kind of audio sprite? If not, why are you skipping the first 5s?

Comment: Suppose I have the audio of a long T.V. show. I want to play using the official mp3 link, but I want users to listen to just the part of the TV show where they interview some person. Then I want the audio to start from that point. I'm going to investigate actionscript and report if I find something.

Comment: If you don't mind using an external player, you might want to give Replayer
 a try: https://web.replayer.app/#/demo  It also has an API to create a clickable link. Note: I am the author of it.

Answer (score 6):

Subzero,
Well, this is 9 years later (ha!) and hope you're still out there. I figured out a way to do it just messing around with different things.  It's super simple.  Here's the syntax below.  I only messed around with it briefly but found that the t=5 needs to be in seconds so 5 is for 5 seconds and 120 would be for two minutes etc.  I couldn't get it to work for minutes.

```
http://../YourSong.mp3#t=5
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

use this code to embed the music

```
<embed type="audio/mpeg" src="http://www.example.com/song.mp3" width="325" height="45" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" autostart="false" loop="false"></embed>
```

create a timer using **javascript** and make `autostart=true`

Examples : [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

---

Check [this](http://www.bigresource.com/JAVASCRIPTS-How-to-delay-autostart-of-playing-music--jlrBDTQW.html) there are few examples you can try out

Comment: Sudantha@: Thanks a lot. But what I want is not to delay the moment when the mp3 starts playing. I want the mp3 to start playing immediately but from 0:05, i.e., I want the user to not hear the first 5 seconds of the song.

Comment: Did u tried Yahoo! Media Player ? http://yahoomediaplayer.wikia.com/wiki/How_To_Link it has lot of options for embedding .. donno what u required is there ! :)

Comment: I tried it, but didn't find a tag to set the moment when the mp3 starts playing.